# Class hierarhy solution

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, application-design

I have  `Activity` class, `ListActivity` class, `TabActivity` class. I want expand these classes using the same functionality. For example add method `toDoSomething()` into each of them. It is impossible to do using мultiple inheritance in Java.

Could you please tell me desing pattern or other solution to resolve this issue without copy-paste

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  Are `ListActivity` and `TabActivity` derived from `Activity`?  If so, put the common functionality into the base class.

Comment: Are you talking about the Android standard activity classes? Why do you want to add a method to each of them? No, multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. No, "code reuse" is not a valid motivation. That's what utility classes are for.

Comment: You will need to create My*Activity classes, declare `IDoSomethingable` with the method and delegate the `toDoSomething()` functionality to other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do less copy-paste if you define your own class `DoSomethingHelper` with `doSomething()` method (probably `doSomething(Activity activity)`), then refer to it from all of your activities as needed. 
I don't know of any better solution.